# How to pass a request object through all middlewares? [Django]

Tags: django, request, django-middleware

I want to call a view inside another view. For that I'm creating an request object and then passing to the view function but I need to populate that request object with a lot of info from the middlewares. My question is how can I pass a request object that I instantiated through all middlewares and then pass it to the view I want?

```
fn, args, kwargs = resolve(kwargs.get('url'))
request = HttpRequest()
# pass through middlewares
fn(request)
```

Comment: Could you use the current `request` in the view, which has already been through the middleware?

Comment: no, there is info that is only added on the middleware depending on the url I'm passing on the request object